# How the mean function parse extra parameter ?

Tags: r

I konw `mean(2,3,4)` is wrong ,but i get still get the result `2`,how R parse the `mean(2,3,4)` ,how mean function parse  extra parameter `3,4`?

```
> mean(2,3,4)
[1] 2
> mean(c(2,3,4))
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R Documentation:

```
 mean(x, ...)

 ## Default S3 method:
 mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...)
```

So `mean(2, 3, 4)` is interpreted as `mean(x=2, trim=3, na.rm=4)` where `4` is evaluated as `TRUE`

As a simple proof we can use this:

```
> mean(2, 3, NA)
Error in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)] : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

or this:

```
>  mean(NA, 3, 4)
[1] NaN

>  mean(NA, 3, 0)
[1] NA
```